# Android: Intent: pass bitmap without compression

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm working on android. I need to save a bitmap without quality lost.

I have tried it using `compress()` method of Bitmap, setting quality to 100. This not works for me, the bitmap loses too much quality. I have tested with JPEG and PNG formats.

I have tested to copy the bitmap to a `ByteBuffer`, then extract the `byte[]` and saving it using a `FileOutputStream`. In this case, I can't display images saved using this way, I only see a blank page.

My question is, is there any way to save a bitmap in SD card without compression?

EDIT: here part of my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    [...]

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent handler){
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, handler);
        if(reqCode == CAPTURE_IDENTIFIER && resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
// THis is that I have tested.
//          Object o = handler.getData();
//          Object o2 = handler.getExtras().getParcelable("data");
//          Object o3 = handler.getExtras().get("data");
//          Object o4 = handler.getParcelableExtra("data");
//          
            prepareCapture();
            startActivityForResult(cameraHandler, CAPTURE_IDENTIFIER);
        }
    }



    private void initCamera(){
        cameraHandler = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraHandler.putExtra("return-data", true);
    }

    private void prepareCapture(){
        currentPhotoName = getNextImageIdentifier() + IMG_BASE_NAME;
        File image = new File(capturesFolder, currentPhotoName);
        Uri uriImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
        cameraHandler.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriImage);
    }



}
```

THe exception i have detected is:
RuntimeException: failure delivering result ResultInfo [...] NullPointerException

EDIT2:
What I have to actually do:

I have to take a photo with the camera, then before save it, I have to process it. After that, i have to save it in SD card. But it's very important the image quality, I can't save it with low quality, or not too low quality at least.

Comment: "I need to save a bitmap without quality lost" -- PNG is a lossless format.

Comment: I have tested JPEG and PNG formats (available formats for Bitmap.compress) with quality = 100 and both lower quality.

Comment: Then your problem is not in the compression, but in how you are creating your `Bitmap` or how you are determining "lower quality".

Comment: I use objects only for check if the intent returns me something

Comment: Can you start explaining what your code should do instead of talking about bitmaps. There is nothing of a bitmap in your code.

Comment: Your code looks completely wrong. There is no startActivityForResult that would trigger onActivityResult.

Comment: It's only a snippet, the first startActivity is in other place,  here is in onActivityResult to make more photos before the first.

Comment: After the first you mean. Take that out. That is very confusing what you do now. Show how you trigger it the first time.

Comment: `then before save it, I have to process it. `. That is impossible if you use this kind of intent with EXTRA_OUTPUT as the image will be saved for you already as jpg.

Comment: Then I have to use the intent without EXTRA_OUTPUT, correct? . OK I have already tried it, and I have already obtained the bitmap from the Intent, my problem is how can I save it in sd card without quality loss.

Comment: Please remove all code. Just post only relevant code which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Done. Now there are   only the methods that I have posted first time.

Comment: Still silly as taking the first picture is not in it. And you should remove taking the next pictures.

Comment: ... It's not important the first photo. A button starts it. that's completely irrelevant.

Comment: Well if you can help yourself be your guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been read the google documentation and this is what I understand, but I'm not sure 100%:

The only way to get an uncompressed image from the android camera is saving it in SD card. Then, if you want to use it, get it from SD.

Indeed, it is not possible to pass an uncompressed image between activities by using intents due to intents can only "transport" objects of "small" size.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using IMAGE_CAPTURE, there is a flag that has to be set to not return a thumbnail.

Without seeing your code, I can only guess.

Documentation:

[Image Capture Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

> Documentation Quote:
>
> If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is
>   returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field

It's a pretty common mistake, please clarify if it's something else.

Comment: I have no EXTRA_OUTPUT because if I use it, when I try to get the image in "onActivityResult", both getData() and getExtra("data") return null.

Comment: No not both. Only parameter Intent data==null.

Comment: Now I can't even  do getData() or getExtras.getParceable("data"), an excepcion occurs.

Comment: Indeed. What kind of exception? Why are you omitting such important info?. Also getData() is not enough info. Show the whole statement in such a case.

Comment: I added additional information. I was trying to avoid it because i thought it would be some function to save uncompressed bitmaps , so that the info wouldn't be neccessary .

Comment: You should have started to tell us where your bitmap did come from. You still did not.