# How to attach photo with better resolution when sending mail Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, email-attachments, android-camera-intent

I made an application in which I take a picture with the camera intent and save it in a bitmap and after that I compress it and take the path of the image and attach it but after testing it and send a test email I observed that the image is rather small (something like `height:100px && width: 50px` but after this I tried to scale it whit the following `height: 500px && width: 250px` to keep the `image ratio` but after testing it again the image was blurry but in my phone the image is bigger and have a better quality and here comes my question how can I do so that the image will be sent bigger and whit a better quality?

P.S: I compress the bitmap in `.JPEG` file and with quality 100%

My intent to open the camera:

```
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        }
    });
```

My startActivityForResult and here is where I create the img file:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        imgBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        img.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
        drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), imgBitmap);
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File dir = new File(path);
        File file = new File(dir, "image.jpeg");
        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            imgBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
}
```

So what can I modify so that the image will have a bigger width and height and it will keep the quality after sending it as an attachment?

Comment: well, even with 100 it is still "compressing". What does it do if you remove 
imgBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
Try other compression utils?

Comment: I think that the image on be created any more :) but i'll try it now :) maybe it will work fine i didn't think about this

Comment: @10101010 it does't work it... the image in email is blan after sending :(

Comment: it might be the email server that is compressing and not the phone, but being blank still sounds strange. Can you try "zipping" the image and then try to send it? 
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compress-files-in-zip-format/

Comment: also take a look at this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649699/android-save-bitmap-without-compression